# How to ensure only a single row with a certain value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE rollouts
(
    id           UUID        PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    device_id    TEXT        NOT NULL,
    is_active    BOOLEAN     NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

How can I ensure that for a given `device_id`, there is only ever **one** active rollout? Multiple inactive ones are fine, so a simple unique index doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a partial unique index:

```
create unique index on rollouts (device_id) 
where is_active;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that out.